# Map take up full height of page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have my map take up 100% the height of the page, but still falling below the navigation bar.

The below screenshot is what I am trying to achieve. How can I rectify so that no matter the device, it always takes up full height of page?

I know I am currently defining the height, but is there a specific class to acheive this?

HTML

```
<div class="column right">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#map {
   width: 100%;
   float: right;
   height: 600px; 
}


.column {
   padding: 10px;
 }
 
 .left {
   width: 55%;
   padding-left: 50px;
   float:left
 }

 .right {
   width: 45%;
   float: right;

 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add `height: 100vh` for viewport height minus the height of your header.
Like this:

`height: calc(100vh - 50px);`. in case your upper bar has a height of 50px.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#map {
   width: 100%;
   float: right;
   height: calc(100vh - 50px);
   background-color: red;
}

 
 .left {
   width: 55%;
   padding-left: 50px;
   float:left
 }

 .right {
   width: 45%;
   float: right;

 }
```

```html
<div class="navigation">navigation / logo</div>
<div class="column right">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

If you want your map full height and your navigation above it, you could try something like, adding `position: absolute` to your logo bar and set the map to `height: 100vh`

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#map {
   width: 100%;
   float: right;
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: red;
}

 
 .left {
   width: 55%;
   padding-left: 50px;
   float:left
 }

 .right {
   width: 45%;
   float: right;

 }
```

```html
<div class="navigation">navigation / logo</div>
<div class="column right">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```